# Magento 2 Generate custom simple products SKU in Configurable products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am looking to generate Custom SKU's for Simple products in configurable products in Magento 2.2.2.

I know we can edit after we create configurations in admin. But I want to slightly change the way SKU is automatically generated.

Right now, it generates 'MAIN_PRODUCT_SKU-**attribute_value_name**'. But I want to change it as '**attribute_value_name**-MAIN_PRODUCT_SKU'.

I dont know the process behind SKU generation and what files are involved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am also looking for a similar thing - not quite the same syntax but does anyone know how to change it?

Answer (score -1):

Sku is generated in js file
/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/web/js/variations/steps/summary.js

in js code:

`sku = productSku + _.reduce(options, function (memo, option) {
                    return memo + '-' + option.label;
                }, '');`

Solution is override it in template or by custom module